# Увеличение цены при создании документа на основании другого документа

Tags: 1с

Есть документ *Заказ* и документ *Расходная накладная*, который создается на основании документа *Заказ*.

в обоих документах есть *Цена*.

как сделать так, чтобы при создании документа *Расходная накладная* на основании документа *Заказ* увеличивалась *Цена* в *Расходной накладной*?

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно смотреть в сторону события "ОбработкаЗаполнения()" в модуле объекта "Расходная накладная"

Answer (score 0):

В модуле расходной накладной есть процедура `ОбработкаЗаполнения()`, там и следует умножать цену.

***P. S.:***
Правильнее было бы хранить "множитель" цены в периодическом регистре сведений.